# Does Unity support hair?

Tags: unity, game-component

As we know, Unity has a cloth component, but is there something to simulate human hair?

Answer (score 0):

No; natively, Unity does not currently have a specific component to simulate hair.

[There are various resources on the Asset Store that center around hair](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=Hair). You might find what you are looking for, there. If not, you will likely have to forgo the inclusion of hair, or otherwise create your own custom game component.